# How to store data on another domain using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, client-side

Say, I have a website DomainA.com which uses java script file from DomainB.com. Now, when a user does some action i need to store data which i can access from DomainB.com, so i started to set cookies from the javascript file loaded from domainB.com, the cookies are stored in the domainA.com instead of domainB.com. 
I am restricted to use javascript to store the data using client side storage like cookies or local storage, How should i approach to store the data on domainB.com in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have access to JS (not Flash, Silverlight, Java, et cetera), and you have no access at all to server-side storage procedures, then there really isn't any way to store and retrieve data on one domain, intended for another domain.

That's by design.

What you're currently asking for would be very helpful for making life easier for developers, but it would also make life very easy for everyone from hackers to data-miners who could just save everything you're doing in a spot set aside from their domain, and then the next time you're on their domain (an ad, running injected JS, perhaps), they can just grab all of that data from all sites you've been on...

Not great.

It's not that preventing this behaviour solves the problem of injected scripts stealing your data, on poorly-secured sites, et cetera, so much as allowing the behaviour makes it unfairly easy to do, and impossible to protect against.

Comment: Thanks Norguard. Looks like i am left with option of using subdomain for setting up shared cookies.